# mysql concat two columns if

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database table which contains two columns "url" of type varchar and "www" of type tinyint which contains 1, if url was specified with www prefix, and 0, if not.

I want create a column in mysql view called full url which would contain following equivalent of c++ code:

```
full_url = "http://" + (www == 1 ? "www." : "") + url;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT('http://', IF(www = 1, 'www.', ''), url) AS full_url FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE`

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN www == 0 /*if not specified with www then add www*/
THEN CONCAT('http://','www.',url) 
ELSE CONCAT('http://',url) /*url contains www*/
END ) `url`
FROM ...
```